# e.target is accessible, but e.target.value is not in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I'm having a strange issue with my React app where I can't get my `deleteTime()` function to work. I was going to try to remove an element from `this.state.times` by using `e.target.value` which would be the `{key}` for the `<li>` I want to remove. The value attribute is getting correctly added to the element, but I just can't access it. I know for a fact that the problem has to do with MaterializeCSS because if I change the element from an `<i>` to a `<button>` without the icons stuff, the code works.

There are basically two components, the main `App` which gives all the props to the `RecentTimes` component which just displays a list of times that are formatted like this: `00 : 00 . 00`

Here is what the `App` component looks like (I removed all the irrelevant stuff):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      times: []
    };
  }

  deleteTime(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // <i value="1" class="material-icons right" data-reactid=".0.0.2.0.0.2:$1.1">close</i>
    console.log(e.target.value); // undefined
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <RecentTimes
        times={this.state.times}
        deleteTime={this.deleteTime}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea why `e.target.value` is undefined if `e.target` clearly has a value attribute.

And here is the component for the RecentTimes:

```
class RecentTimes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let icons = 'material-icons right';

    let times = this.props.times.map((time, timeIndex) => {
      return (
        <li key={timeIndex}>
          {time}
          <i value={timeIndex} onClick={this.props.deleteTime} className={icons}>close</i>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>{times}</ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does an `i` have a value attribute?

Comment: Sorry, it may be unclear from my description. The `<i>` tag is basically being used to make an icon that looks like `X` next to the time. Clicking on it will go to the `deleteTime()` function. By giving it a value, I can delete the right value in `this.state.times` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a data attribute

```
<i data-value={timeIndex} onClick={this.props.deleteTime} className={icons}>close</i>
```

and

```
e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
```

or if the browser supports [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
e.target.dataset.value
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Do you know why `value` worked for other tags, but not for `<i>`?

Comment: I've got the same issue when using <a> tag, and this solution works too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use e.target.id.

```js
class RecentTimes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let icons = 'material-icons right';

    let times = this.props.times.map((time, timeIndex) => {
      return (
        <li key={timeIndex}>
          {time}
          <i id={timeIndex} onClick={this.props.deleteTime} className={icons}>close</i>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>{times}</ul>
    );
  }
}
```